# R Replacing colnames based on matching names in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, matching

I want to rename some columns in a dataframe based on another dataframe. I have 2 dataframes, one with codes as columnnames and a seconds one with a list of codes and a string.

```
df = as.data.frame(matrix(NA, 3, 60)) colnames(df) = c(paste0(sprintf("S%s",seq(10,19))), paste0(sprintf("R%s",seq(20,50))), paste0(sprintf("F%s",seq(51,69))))

namelist = as.data.frame(c(paste0(sprintf("B%s",seq(10,19))), paste0(sprintf("R%s",seq(20,50))), paste0(sprintf("A%s",seq(51,69)))))
colnames(namelist) = "Code"
myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))}
namelist$Name = myFun(nrow(namelist))
```

I want to rename now the colnames in df, which are listed in the in the namelist. Their new name should be the string standing behind that matching code in the namelist.

The result should be then: Keeping the columnnames that are not listed as a code in namelist and replacing R20-R50 with the string.

I need a solution that is really taking the code in one piece because I also might have combined Codes as columnanmes, like R40+R41, which should not be renamed.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: As it is a `sample`, my results would not same as yours without a `set.seed`.  Can you check whether the solution I provided is what you expect  logically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the index

```
i1 <- match(colnames(df), namelist$Code)
i2 <- !is.na(i1) # to take care of non matches which are NA
names(df)[i2] <- namelist$Name[i1[i2]]
names(df)
#[1] "S10"        "S11"        "S12"        "S13"        "S14"        "S15"        "S16"        "S17"        "S18"       
#[10] "S19"        "NRROX3720Q" "AJDIO5627R" "PNGQI9045F" "PMRKH3945W" "AWTUS8801K" "FAUSS0775K" "RHMDT7354P" "EHFXN5677T"
#[19] "DEXAD5460Z" "XNPJU6465R" "ISLKV8962F" "ZVAAT4099D" "MWCLD5013G" "MSSCG1315D" "NKJBC5303V" "EDHHR9300M" "CVWHP7658I"
#[28] "BPUSL4348S" "LPEWZ1407A" "QACRV3987M" "XMHYQ8544N" "UJGRX9778J" "KPAYY3203M" "JTETK9509P" "VYNYF6624P" "RDDZD3099N"
#[37] "SHUES3288G" "CGFKB5625F" "WTUEX0452E" "BSDUR3721G" "BZMND9193I" "F51"        "F52"        "F53"        "F54"       
#[46] "F55"        "F56"        "F57"        "F58"        "F59"        "F60"        "F61"        "F62"        "F63"       
#[55] "F64"        "F65"        "F66"        "F67"        "F68"        "F69"
```

i.e. if there are no match, the column name remain as such

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, even though I dont really understand it. :) I will look up the last line, I dont get that at all. But thank you so much!

Comment: The `match` returns the index.  If there are no match, by default it is `NA`.  the second line checks for that NA and return TRUE when there is no NA.  We use that 'i2' to subset 'i1', at the same time subset the column names on the lhs as well.  Because `match` gives position, get the 'Name' based on that position

Comment: I got that, I understand the index-stuff, but the namelist$Name[i1[i2]], I have never seen that. I didnt know that [i1[i2]] exists.

Comment: @Mr.Spock It is just a. secondary index on the index